# Trouble With Python os.system

Tags: python

I am writing a program where you create a file by imputing a title, and the text that you wish to have in the file. The program asks if you are sure that you want to delete the file. A simple task, right? Yes, but there is one more factor that needs to be considered. My program saves the text file to d DIFFERENT folder that the program is in. By default, the file that the program is creating is saved to the folder that the program is in, unless you provide a custom file path for it to save. Well, it also trys to delete the file from the folder that the program is in. But I want to delete the file from the folder that the FILES are in. That is where it gets tricky.
Here Is My Code:

```
    import os
    SaveDir = "/home/marc/QuickJotTexts"
    if nub == "n":
        os.path.join(SaveDir) + os.system("rm " +title)
```

Please Note That SaveDir is The Folder Where I Want The Files To Save.

As Y=you can probably see, this is a very small part of my code. If you need any more information, post it in the comments.

THANKS!

Marc-

Comment: you need `os.system("rm " +os.path.join(SaveDir, title))`, otherwise you are trying to add a string with the result of `rm <title>` in a context where the file does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.join` returns a string containing a pathname. You're trying to concatenate that with a call to the shell to `rm %title`, which obviously doesn't work (it's like doing 2+apple, it just doesn't make sense.)

Instead you need to run `os.system("rm {}".format(os.path.join(SaveDir,title)))` to join `SaveDir` and `title` together as a pathname, then format that into the string to send to the shell.

That said, wouldn't `os.remove` work better for this?

Comment: In all honesty, i didnt even think to use os.remove. could you explain to me how to do that please.

Comment: @user3470203 same way you'd use this, except skipping the unnecessary system call. `os.remove(filename)` deletes the file at the path `filename`